# Scrapping , No Class attribute

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

For whatever reason I keep getting 0 results:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pandas .io.html import read_html

source= requests.get('https://www.ss.lv/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/all/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
scrape=soup.find_all("tbody", class_=None )
print(len(scrape))
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any `<tbody>` in the source HTML. Try to use method to select correct tag(s) (CSS selector/bs4 api):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://www.ss.lv/lv/real-estate/flats/riga/all/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.find_all("tr", id=lambda i: i and i.startswith("tr_")):
    tds = [
        text
        for td in tr.select("td")
        if (text := td.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
    ]
    # print some sample data:
    if tds:
        print(tds[0], tds[-1])
```

Prints:

```
Izīrēšanai piedāvāju saulainu un plašu 3-istabu dzīvokli. Dzīvok 330 €/mēn.
Īpašnieks pārdod saulainu, gaišu un siltu 2 istabu dzīvokli Mežc 49,800  €
Tiek pārdots gaišs un silts divu istabu dzīvoklis. 

Dzīvoklī 51,000 €
Pārdod gaišu un patīkamu 2 līmeņa 3-istabu dzīvoklis. 
Ar mājas 88,000  €
Продаём просторную, солнечную 2-х комнатную квартиру - наше семе 119,800 €
Pārdod 3 istabu dzīvokli. Oriģinālais plānojums, liela virtuve, 60,000  €
Istabas izolētas. Lodžija. 
Stikla pakešu logi un dzelžs durvis 47,000  €
Pārdodas gaišs un patīkams 3-istabu dzīvokli lieliskā lokācijā T 71,070  €
Сдаётся маленькая квартира студия общей площадью 18 кв. м. Мален 120  €/mēn.
В самом сердце города, в историческом здании 19 века напротив Но 560 €/mēn.

...and so on.
```

Comment: Your code worked, but I am such a noob, I just don't know what I would do next to get specific categories that I need.

Comment: @AliseValeiņa I suggest to go step by step. Select one tag that you need, then select all on the page. beautifulsoup has nice documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: The usage of `:=` within `if (text:=td.text)` appears to be foreign to me. Is this feature recently added @Andrej?

Comment: @SIM `:=`, thats python assignment operator ("walrus" operator). Available from Python 3.8 and above. https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/

Comment: hey @AndrejKesely I came up this print
        print(tds[1],tds[2],tds[3],tds[4], tds[6])
      BUT, IT only works for the first page. Can you please advise how could I do multiple pages so it would just keep looping?